# Laravel change timezone

Tags: php, laravel, apache, date, utc

After changing app/config/app.php FROM: `'timezone' => 'UTC'`, which is the default TO: `'timezone' => 'Europe/Vilnius'`, and still getting wrong date output. Also I changed php.ini file

```
[Date]
date.timezone=Europe/Vilnius
```

and restarted apache server, still getting wrong date output.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the config cache:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set your Application Time Zone by configuring app.php file in config folder. To change time zone

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Vilnius'
```

And clear the config cache execute this command : 
    php artisan optimize:clear

You do not have the privileges to execute that command, you can delete the cached config file.

It is located at bootstrap/cache/config.php.

Comment: There was no need to run `php artisan optimize:clear`, just changed timezone value in app.php file and it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In order to reflect your timezone related changes of your config file then kindly ensure that you have cleared your cache. You can use the following command set for your reference:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: There was no need to run above commands, just changed `timezone` value in `app.php` file and it worked for me. Thanks.